# How to update UI and ask Permission for Healthkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, healthkit

Nowadays I am working on an app related to Healthkit in iOS. I am facing a problem.
In the first view controller, which is HomeVC, when I tried to ask for healthkit permission, it's working fine, and show a system screen for permission.

But Meanwhile, I have to setup the layout of UI elements on viewcontoller with asking permission, So I added some code to update UI in viewDidload method. In that case when I ask permission, the permission screen not showing and showing white screen, and following error in the console.

> Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=100 "Authorization session timed
> out" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Authorization session timed out}

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Add into info.plist file. Add following
Information property List -> Privacy - Health Update Usage Description
Description -> App wants to access your health kit to provide you better fitness result

```
func authorizeHealthKit() {
        
        let healthKitTypesToRead : Set<HKObjectType> = [
            HKObjectType.characteristicType(forIdentifier: HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifier.dateOfBirth)!,
            HKObjectType.characteristicType(forIdentifier: HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifier.bloodType)!,
            HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!,
            HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .activeEnergyBurned)!
        ]
        let healthKitTypes: Set = [ HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)!, HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.activeEnergyBurned)! ]
        
        
        let healthKitTypesToWrite : Set<HKSampleType> = []
        
        if !HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
            
            print("error")
            return
        }
        self.healthKitStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: healthKitTypesToWrite, read: healthKitTypesToRead) { (success, error) in
            print("request authorized succesfully")      
        }
        
        
    }
```